# How to sort dictionaries by keys in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Can anyone tell me how I can sort this:

```
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'c': ['one', 'two'], 'b': ['blah', 'bhasdf', 'asdf'], 'd': ['asdf', 'wer', 'asdf', 'zxcv']}
```

into

```
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': ['blah', 'bhasdf', 'asdf'], 'c': ['one', 'two'],'d': ['asdf', 'wer', 'asdf', 'zxcv']}
```

?
Thanks!

UPDATE 1, code sample:

So I am doing linguistics. One article is broken down to words that are stored in a database and have all kinds of properties including para ID and sentence ID. The task: trying to rebuild the original text.

Get 500 consecutive words from DB

```
words = Words.objects.all()[wordId:wordId+500]
# I first create paragraphs, through which I can loop later in my django template,
# and in each para will be a list of words (also dictionaries). 
# So i am trying to get a dictionary with values that are lists of dictionaries. 
# 'pp' i make just for shorthanding a long-named variable.
paras={}
para_high = para_low =  words[0].belongs_to_paragraph
for w in words:
    last_word = w
    pp = w.belongs_to_paragraph
    if pp >para_high:
        para_high = pp
    if pp < para_low:
        para_low = pp
    if pp in paras:
        paras[pp].append(w)
    else:
        list = [w]
        paras[pp] = list
# Since there are blank lines between paragraphs, in rebuilding the text as it 
    #  looked originally, I need to insert blank lines. 
    # Since i have the ID's of the paragraphs and they go somewhat like that: 1,3,4,8,9 
    #(the gaps between 1 & 3 and 4 & 8 i have to fill in with something else, 
    # which is why i had para_low and para_high to loop the range. 
isbr = True
for i in range(para_low, para_high+1):
    if i in paras:
        isbr = True
    else:
        if isbr:
            paras[i]=['break']
            isbr = False
        else:
            paras[i]=[]
```

At this point, however, if I try to loop the dict and rebuild the text, some later id'd paragraphs come before previous ones, and that just doesn't do it.

UPDATE 2, loop code:

```
        {% for k,v in wording.iteritems()  %}
        {% if v[0] == 'break' %}
        <br/>
        {% else %}
        </div><div class="p">{% for word in v %}{% if word.special==0%} {% endif %}<span class="word {% if word.special == 0%}clickable{% endif%}" wid="{{word.id}}" special="{{word.special}}" somethingElse={{word.somethingElse}}>{{ word.word }}</span>{% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: ... and **why**, exactly, do you want this?

Comment: i guess the code now illustrates why i want that

Comment: "If i try to loop the dict and try to rebuild the text, some later id-d paragraphs come before previous ones and just doesn't do it."  Yes. So **use `sorted()`**. Really, It' that easy.

Comment: i have: paras=sorted(paras) in my view, but what happens is that i lose the structure of my data of the word dictionaries. word['type']='verb', word['special']='true' and i get error: "'list' object has no attribute 'keys'"

Comment: No, you don't get a "loose structure" you get a sorted list of key/value tuples from your dictionary, which you then can loop over. And you should reasonably (as per my example) use `sorted()` in the loop; `for k,v in sorted(paras):` or similar. Also, you completely skipped the relevant part of the code, namely the loop.

Comment: I didn't mean that i get "loose structure" but that i lose it, i don't have anymore, i can't access the values of my words by their keys. Actually, i now realize my words are NOT Dictionaries, they are objects. "for k,v in sorted(paras):"-> gives me "sorted is undefined"

Comment: Ah, so the `.belongs_to_paragraph` is not a built in type, but something else. What type of object is it? Can you get something sortable out of it? Like pp = `w.belongs_to_paragraph.value` or something?

Comment: No, wait, `sorted() is undefined`!? Can you tell me the *exact* error message? Is it "NameError: name 'sorted' is not defined"? Then you are using a *very* old Python (namely 2.3 or older).

Comment: If that helps, i am working in django with jinja templating. so {% for k,v in wording %} gives me "Exception Type:  TypeError" || "Exception Value:  'long' object is not iterable". Then if i do sorted(wording) i get: UndefinedError || 'sorted' is undefined. And if i try to sort the stuff in the view, i get the UndefinedError||"list' object has no attribute 'keys'" error.

Comment: belongs_to_paragraph is an integer column in my mysql db

Comment: Oh, so you cant use sorted() in Django templates? Ah well, just pass in `sorted(paras)` instead of just `paras` from Python, and it should still work. So *not* set "paras = sorted(paras)" that changes paras from a dict to a list. Just pass in sorted(paras) into the template. But now we are into Django territory. If you can't get it to work, I suggest you make a new question on how to sort an iterable in a Django template. :)

Comment: But sorted always converts a dict to a list, so it will eventually pass a list again. The template can loop dict but the problem i i can 't prepare pythonically the right thing. anyway, i admire your energy to help and patience

Comment: @mgPepe Yes, sorry, my bad, you need to pass sorted(paras.iteritems()), so you get both the key and the value. Anyhow, there should be a way to sort things in Django, so ask a question on that. If not, then OrderedDict is a useable workaround for this Django problem.

Comment: Yeah, i fill figure it out. I might try to use ordered if i can't figure it out, thanx a lot

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Dicts don't have an order.

You can call sorted but this just gives you a sorted list of the keys:

```
>>> sorted(d)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

You can treat it as an iterable and sort the key-value tuples, but then you've just got a list of tuples. That's not the same as a dict.

```
>>> sorted(d.items())
[
 ('a', [1, 2, 3]),
 ('b', ['blah', 'bhasdf', 'asdf']),
 ('c', ['one', 'two']),
 ('d', ['asdf', 'wer', 'asdf', 'zxcv'])
]
```

If you are using Python 2.7 or newer you could also consider using an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

> dict subclass that remembers the order entries were added

For example:

```
>>> d = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))
>>> for k, v in d.items():
>>>     print k, v
```

```
a [1, 2, 3]
b ['blah', 'bhasdf', 'asdf']
c ['one', 'two']
d ['asdf', 'wer', 'asdf', 'zxcv']
```

Comment: well, but that doesn't help me much, does it? maybe there isn't a built in function, but there is a more complicated user-written solution?

Comment: The OrderedDict mention wasn't there in the original version of the answer.

Comment: @mgPePe looks like a suitable answer to me, and a reasonable solution for you - if not, can you give more details on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Ordered != sorted. If he wants the items **sorted** he should sort the keys with the sorted() function. If he wants them **ordered** he should use an OrderedDict.

Comment: @Matt - i am trying to get a sorted dictionary. OrderedDict sounds the right thing, except it was added later in a newer version of python, and it doesn't work in 2.6. I get "ImportError: cannot import name OrderedDict". What I am trying to get is another ordered dictionary, and not a list of items. Just to make sure i got it:the problem is that regular Dict in python does not have an ordering concept at all, and not that it doesn't have a prebuilt function to sort it, is this what you mean by "Dicts don't have an order. You can't sort them."?

Comment: @mgPepe: FYI: in my answer, you'll find a link to the canonical implementation (linked in the official documentation) for Python 2.4 --> Python 2.6.

Comment: @Lennart - considering your point, it looks like i need a sorted Dict, not an ordered Dict, right? Basically what function would turn the variable from the first line of the question into a variable with the second line in this question?

Comment: @mgPepe: Nothing would turn it into that. You need to call sorted() each time you loop over the items of the dictionary. See my answer. If you are going to loop several times with the same sorting and no manipulations (unlikely) you can use sorted() to make it into a list of (key, value) tuples.

Comment: Thanx guys, very helpful. This definitely explains the issue. I will go for now with the pure python solution of @ChristopheD & @Nicholas, just because of my outdated python, otherwise this gives me quite the answer. Great help!

Answer (score 37):

The **correct** answer is that if you want the items of a dictionary in a sorted order, you should use the sorted() function *when you loop over the dictionary*:

```
for k, v in sorted(d.items()):
    print k, ':', v
```

or

```
for k in sorted(d):
   print d[k]
```

Or similar.

The OrderedDict mentioned is for dictionaries that have an order. And order is not the same as a sorting. You can create a sorted OrderedDict, yes, but as soon as you add a new key it is no longer sorted. **So you would need to use sorted() anyway** to sort it before each use or after each manipulation. The OrderedDict is therefore only slower and more memory intensive than an ordinary dictionary, while adding nothing you need.

OrderedDict are *not* for sorted dictionaries, but for dictionaries where the items have some sort of ordering that is *not* a sorting. Such as if you want to show things in the order they were added, or if you want you users to be able to order things arbitrarily.

**Update: Further explanation**

Why is OrderedDict not a solution? Because an OrderedDict is *ordered* not *sorted*.

Consider a standard dictionary:

```
>>> d = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5}
```

It's not sorted, as we see below, 'c' will come before 'b'. It also has no order, if we add new things it appears what seems like random order:

```
>>> d['g'] = 6
>>> d['i'] = 8
>>> d
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 4, 'd': 3, 'g': 6, 'f': 5, 'i': 8}
```

OK, so let's use an OrderedDict then:

```
>>> o = OrderedDict(sorted({'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5}.items()))
>>> o
OrderedDict([('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 3), ('e', 4), ('f', 5)])
```

Aha! Sorted! So OrderedDict works!? No.

```
>>> o['i'] = 8
>>> o['g'] = 6
>>> o
OrderedDict([('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 3), ('e', 4), ('f', 5), ('i', 8), ('g', 6)])
```

What? The g ended up *after* the i?!? Why!? Because the OrderedDict is not sorted, it's *ordered*. It remembers the *order* you add things. Not the sorting. This means that every time you use it you need to sort it first. An OrderedDict will only stay sorted as long as you don't add keys to it. But if you aren't going to modify it, then you don't need a dict. You can just as well have a list. Which is what you get from sorted():

```
>>> sorted(o.items())
[('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 3), ('e', 4), ('f', 5), ('g', 6), ('i', 8)]
```

But that works just as well with the standard dictionary, so the OrderedDictionary didn't help:

```
>>> sorted(d.items())
[('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 3), ('e', 4), ('f', 5), ('g', 6), ('i', 8)]
```

**Conclusion**
So each time you want to loop over the dictionary in a sorted way, you need to do:

```
>>> for k in sorted(o):
...   print k, o[k]
... 
a 0
b 1
c 2
d 3
e 4
f 5
g 6
i 8
```

And that is *no matter what dictionary you use*. OrderedDict doesn't really help you, because it doesn't care about *sorting*, just the *order* you add things in.

Comment: + 1 since you interpreted the question correctly, I'll delete my (wrong) answer in a moment (or I'll delete it tomorrow for completeness' sake) ;-)

Comment: hmm, but the problem arises when you try to build the new Dict. Let's take your first loop. It does print correctly something of the sort: a:1, b:2, c:3 and so on. However, when you try to replace the print line with new_dict[k]=v and then print v in the interpreter, you get another NOT sorted dictionary with a:1, c:3, b:2

Comment: @mgPePe: "The new dict"? "Another"? Dictionaries are *not* sorted. You need to use sorted() when you loop over them. Always.

Comment: @lennart: i am a newbie, and i am having hard time implementing this. Here's why: i have an article. it's broken into paras, sentences, words. i am analyzing linguistics. each word has it's para ID, sentence ID and also a bunch of properties. i would like to rebuild the original text by joining the words together. 

I pull 500 words ordered by ID and store them in a dict, but then after I do a couple operations, the words are no more sorted, and the text i am trying to rebuild is a mess.

Comment: @mgPepe: Yes so you must sort the dictionaries when they are ready for rebuilding. And you use `sorted()` to do that. You loop over the dictionaries when rebuilding, right? Just stick a sorted() around them in that loop. If that doesn't work, post the relevant bit of your code. *Unless* you don't actually want it sorted, you want it ordered, ie, the same order when you take them out as when you put them in. Then you can use an OrderedDict from the start instead of a standard dict.

Comment: Ok, let me paste my code to illustrate as an update to the question.

Answer (score 5):

It's worth noting that Python has a number of dictionary implementations that maintain the keys in sorted order. Consider the [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) module which is pure-Python and fast-as-C implementations. There's a [performance comparison](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance.html) with other fast and feature-complete implementations benchmarked against one another.

For example:

```
>>> from sortedcontainers import SortedDict
>>> d = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'c': ['one', 'two'], 'b': ['blah', 'bhasdf', 'asdf'], 'd': ['asdf', 'wer', 'asdf', 'zxcv']}
>>> s = SortedDict(**d)
>>> s.keys()
SortedSet(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

You can also entirely replace your use of dict with [SortedDict](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html) as it supports fast get/set operations and sorted iterations of items by key.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and easy function you can use to sort a dictionary by keys.

## Put this code in a separate file called `sdict.py`:

```
def sortdict(dct):
    kys = dct.keys()
    kys.sort()
    from collections import OrderedDict
    d = OrderedDict()
    for x in kys: 
        for k, v in dct.iteritems():
            if (k == x):
                d[k] = v
    return d
```

## Now, place this code into a separate file called `test.py` to test it with a sample dictionary:

```
from sdict import sortdict
import json
dct = {'sizes':[32,28,42], 'dog':'schnauser', 'cat':'siamese', 'bird':'falcon'}
dctx = sortdict(dct)
print json.dumps(dctx)
```

## And finally, call `test.py` from the command line:

```
$ python test.py
{"bird": "falcon", "cat": "siamese", "dog": "schnauser", "sizes": [32, 28, 42]}
```

I'm only using json.dumps line to show you that it's an actual dictionary, and not just a string representation. You can also test it with the type() function for that matter.

I included a nested list with numeric values in the sample dictionary to show that the function can handle more complex dictionaries, not just single-layer string-based dicts.

The code is pretty straightforward, so it would be easy to modify it to sort by values, if that's your preference - although sorting by value would not make sense if some of the values are objects, like lists, tuples or other dicts.

Admittedly, this only works in python 2.7 or later.

Cheers,
-=Cameron

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer mentioned, the order of a dictionary's keys is arbitrary and you shouldn't rely on it.

If you're using Python 2.7 or 3.1 or later, try out `collections.OrderedDict` ([2.7 docs](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects); [3.1 docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects); also see [PEP 372](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0372/)). There's a link in the docs to a [pure-Python version of OrderedDict](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/) that works on earlier Python versions.

Answer (score 0):

It may also be worth mentioning the nlargest routine in heapq. This sorts and returns the top N items. Depending upon what is actually required, this may be handy if you play with the key parameter. I mainly mention this since I discovered it a couple of nights ago and it did exactly what I was after. See [PEP 0265](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0265/) and [Heapq](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html).

Answer (score 0):

I will add my one cent to what others already explained. I happened to have the exact same problem in one specific case. I needed the output of my dictionary to always be the same for writing stable unit-tests.

If by chance it is what you are trying to achieve, or some other output related task, you don't have to sort anything at all, just use `pprint` module, among other features it will sort dictionaries by keys.

```
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
>>> print d
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(d)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: thanx @kriss, i read another question on SO about it, but print is not what i need by itself, and also i think it doesn't sort in all versions of python